# Series expansion and Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I need to find the series expansion at $$z=0$$ and the Laurent series  at $$  \sqrt{ 2/3} <|z| < \infty $$
for the function $$ f(z)= \frac{1}{(2-3z^{2})^2} $$
I guess I first need to  first find the partial fraction decomposition

Comment: It seems like you already know what you need to do.  Maybe try computing the partial fraction decomposition and edit your question if you are still unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\;f(z)=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac12\right)^2}{\left(1-\dfrac32z^2\right)^2}=\dfrac {\left(\dfrac1{3z^2}\right)^2}{\left(1-\dfrac2{3z^2}\right)^2}\;$ and $\;\dfrac 1{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots$